# using require_once in Symfony's project configuration class

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, relative-path

In my ProjectConfiguration.class.php file, I am trying to ensure that the filepath to `sfCoreAutoload.class.php` is dynamic and doesn't require me to manually change it each time I log online, which as most of you would know requires you to enter the line below:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
```

*(refer http://symfony.com/blog/jobeet-day-23-the-deployment)*

My Symfony files are stored in:

```
Users/username/lib/vendor/symfony-1.4.14/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php`
```

which would essentially translate to:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/vendor/symfony-1.4.14/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
```

But this does not work and my localhost says server not found.

The above to me does not make sense anyways as the Project configuration file is stored in :

```
symfony/lib/config/sfProjectConfiguration.class.php
```

and the Autoload file in:

```
symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php
```

so technically this should translate to:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php'
```

That does not work either, relegating me to mention full paths for both prod and dev environments and hence having me to manually make the change each time I push it live (obviously making the process less seamless and DUMB).

Does anybody know what's up here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is a good solution to keep your Symfony folder independent of your project, if you want to share it for example.

I recommend your keep the **default path**:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
```

Then, simply create a **symbolic link**, to your symfony folder.

```
cd /path/to/your/project/lib/vendor
ln -s Users/username/lib/vendor/symfony-1.4.14/ symfony
```

Comment: yes naturally this is what the intention is, and this is what the book says, but you did not read the problem in detail, the path does not render itself as it ought to !